# Hasura querying becomes slower For Tracked SQL Function

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, performance, hasura

For `tracked SQL function`, hasura query is taking a lot of time but when it is executed from `SQL` directly it takes only few milliseconds to get the data. We are not able to figure out what is the actual problem as we are using `Postgresql DB`

We followed some steps to reduce the response time

- Applying `indexes` on `DB`
- Analysing the `query plan` to reduce the cost
- Querying only a `limited set of data` to reduce the response size

We tried to run that query from SQL directly which only took few milliseconds but when when try to run from `hasura query` it took a lot of time for `same parameters`

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that it is probably due to permissions that are being evaluated when you run the function through Hasura.

When you were analysing the query plan, did you also make sure that you were passing in roles to ensure that the plan captures any additional changes to the query that are required in order for the permissions to be evaluated?

Comment: I don't think that is a permission issue , because it is running  by admin role